# How to explain advantage and disadvantage of one particular thing in the same sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

I am working on a statistical method. I would like to describe one main step of this method in one sentence. This step has a good and weak point.

Here is my try:

The free choice of the parameters is one of the main strength of the structure method, and it also forms one of the main challenge parts.

I feel that my sentence is very weak.

Any help, please?

Comment: "one of the main **strengths**" (plural).

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by **structure method**.

Comment: Are you trying to say that being able to choose the parameters is one of the main advantages of the approach, but knowing which parameters to choose can be a challenge?

Comment: Read up on how to use the word **although**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, yes. your comment is what I really need. It is amazing. Could you post it as an answer, please?

Comment: Maryam, in general you need to ask a more specific question than you have done here, since the rules of this site would treat your question as a request for proofreading.  So I will leave it as a comment for now :)  Welcome to ELL. There are many people here who are willing to help learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these sentences mean that the free choice of the parameters is the advantage of the structure method,but at the same time it forms one of the main challenges.I took the liberty to rephrase your sentence.

- The free choice of the parameters is one of the main strengths of the structure method, **but** it is also one of the main challenges.
- The free choice of the parameters is one of the main strengths of the structure method. **However**, it is also one of the main challenges.
- The free choice of the parameters is one of the main strengths of the structure method, **although** it is also one of the main challenges.(you may even use **though** which is the short form of although)
- The free choice of the parameters is one of the main strengths of the structure method, **even though/if** it is also one of the main challenges.
- The free choice of the parameters is one of the main strengths of the structure method,**despite the fact that**  it is also one of the main challenges.